# How to display checkbox, that binds dynamically using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to display checkbox that binds dynamically using ajax and php  .

my code is

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM city where district_id='$dist' ");

while($city_row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $city_row['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $city_row['city_name']; ?>
<?php
}
}

?>
```

ajax script

```
$.ajax({

type: "POST",
cache: false,
url: "get_locality.php",
    data:{districts:hi },
success: function(response){
    alert(response);
    $('#city').html(response);

}
});
```

html div

```
<div class="checkbox" ><span id="city">

                            </span>

                        </div>
```

but it only displays the values . not displaying the checkboxes

Comment: `$dist` where is that defined?

Comment: `districts:hi` where are those defined?

Comment: Seems like I've fallen onto deaf ears.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you print only the value of checkbox and not the checkbox html. So  store all code inside one variable and print that variable.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM city where district_id='$dist' ");
$str = '';
while($city_row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$str .= '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$city_row['id'].'"/>'.$city_row['city_name'];
}
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use below code"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yes @JayBlanchard , You are right. I add description of the issue. Thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: Another solution with double quotes (more readable in my opinion), which avoid the multiple concatenations: `$str .= "<input type='checkbox' value='{$city_row['id']}'/>{$city_row['city_name']}";`